# How can I add react 360 on a regular react site?

Tags: reactjs, react-360

I want to add 3d viewing option to my navigation. Currently, I see the only option is to add react-360 as an iframe but how can I actually take them from my regular site to 360 mode?  Please see example below. If you click on view on wall that's exactly what's I'm looking to do

https://addisfineart.com/exhibitions/79/works/artworks-12477-selome-muleta-tsedal-i-2020/

Comment: on your example is "nothing 3D", it's just well positioned PNGs with CSS

Comment: Is there a recommended tutorial to do something like that? Did you click on view on wall?

Comment: yes, I did... and it uses perspective to simulate 3D... just fake 3D in a simple way... ;)